# Saving Data to a Txt File Doesn't Result in Columns

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, text-files, multiple-columns

I am trying to save data from two arrays in a text file. I want them to be in columns. After using, my code, it places them in arrays within my text file.

I have tried opening and writing to a file, while saving the data to the file I opened. This results in arrays with []s inside my text file. I want each array to be a separate column.

```
listkH2=[]
with open ("Basecol_HCL_H2_para_space.txt", 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        listkH2.append(map(float, line.strip().split('\t')[4:]))

listkHe=[]
with open ("Lamda_HeHCL.txt", "r") as data:
    for line in data:
        listkHe.append(map(float, line.strip().split('\t')[3:]))


listkH2 = np.array(listkH2)
listkHe = np.array(listkHe)

listkHe = zip(*listkHe)
listkH2 = zip(*listkH2)

g = len(listkH2[4])
h = len(listkH2)

base = 10
exponentkH2 = np.log(listkH2)/np.log(base)
exponentkHe = np.log(listkHe)/np.log(base)
exponentR = np.log(R)/np.log(base)

exponentkHe.resize(exponentkH2.shape)


sub_arr = np.subtract(exponentkH2, exponentkHe)

C = sub_arr/exponentR
# m, b=np.polyfit(Delta,C,1)

with open('final_all_temperatures.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(0,h):
        f.write(str(C[i]) + '\t')
```

This is the result of my text file.

```
[ 2.05096059  3.65564871  0.25845727  2.86561982  1.45278606  1.43600254
  2.56773896  2.45761421  1.20582346  0.60828049  3.26240446  4.27576383
  0.54857546 -0.64695867 -0.11224826  5.17238434  2.98451642  3.85145269
  3.09965407  2.52651157 -3.00785759  4.3324366   2.80269088  2.45654687
  3.47455066  2.65614389  0.27125519  0.25980975  7.09469104  6.99091224
  0.87473021  1.10630048  0.87345859  0.97107587 -0.27617078 -1.30076657
  6.77947741  5.90616421  4.5975132   5.11154511  5.25644884  5.31593925
 -1.99289632 -2.3974694  -3.80162209  5.13590939  3.98362836  4.46667132
  4.10673705  3.77926953  3.94386828  3.30850352  1.95047033  1.76710167
  1.19894221 10.18390848  1.78371439  2.49395868  2.3474523   2.519068
  1.38826942  2.05602612  1.25479554  0.96399962  0.11317195 -1.10848421
  8.53820213  7.633488    7.12863018  7.63910202  8.10127737  7.87049188
 -1.91641511 -0.28726499 -1.29462024 -1.25186861 -2.50127217 -3.22243846
  5.68118123  6.23469673  5.63422048  5.91636457  5.68482542  5.5662473
  5.07251286  4.9056646   4.37984497  4.62261653  4.25979296  3.72784228
 -7.88586841  5.25835441  1.23747084  4.6921546   2.66446001  4.40904565
  2.19600568  4.0688489   0.68169022  3.43846513  1.67349861  2.63996661
  0.1540953   0.94775071 -2.36103131 10.93013689  9.09044102 10.78030914
  9.49466186 11.26694864]   [10.80376405 10.93396947  8.78331386  8.66009656  7.53236037  7.99974278
  5.22439242  4.28218218  3.03594372  2.16010528 12.82404951 13.3732189
  9.05826637  9.18144497 10.56296634 10.09347188  9.04596931  9.61318739
  8.54461674  9.12830347  4.26666193  4.5667606   3.54283205  2.95557657
  2.88977065  1.0935233  12.59595864 13.00536833 12.6136856  13.00661573
  7.26336223  7.67990927  7.30171157  7.91066542  7.455629    7.2838736
  7.58015125  6.82723242  5.35373085  5.71033646  5.18946539  4.49244374
 -3.51515573 10.30278666  9.38098429  9.94790116  9.25593545  9.83329325
  9.63878409  9.53483308  9.73113818  9.22097715  8.37749349  8.89604493
  9.10481854  8.86047563  0.62755156  0.93984665  0.10698098 -0.39034919
 -2.69513211 12.15017732 11.13286652 11.43125376 11.32322433 11.1926892
 11.22782336 10.87236282 10.4539346  10.98570189 11.38457084 11.25752581
  1.21225179  3.07424717  2.01456061  2.44766602  1.26953183  1.0984022
 -1.29397618 -1.48139497 12.60977098 12.54882608 12.1162488  12.21761522
 11.8101766  11.90699102 11.49715631 12.24025124 12.37510349 12.67056169
  2.13545973  4.28512186  0.62778423  3.92076771  1.67268049  2.97473961
  0.31064791  1.51748601 -2.5543087  -1.17402789 -3.59412271 -1.0003402
 -4.10661142 -0.05811249 -2.34663317 -1.61805463  0.47613233  2.36532043
  0.54560575  1.16125952]   [ 4.9855747   5.03496604  3.42614786  2.22158852  0.38884903  6.90865818
  3.39190522  3.33552032  3.05084431  2.12397894 -0.2323361   7.53797668
  2.25622511  2.02602316  3.60604263  2.91488229  0.83429121  0.53335524
  6.63836166  6.96359602  1.86327326  2.32811345  1.89414417  1.46912454
  1.26198015 -0.21686245  6.20160265  6.73493949  6.17160435  6.29832781
  0.46716077  0.86182049 -0.09054745 -0.29874062 -1.67545908  6.62483228
  6.60375835  6.04711012  4.73844679  5.37803451  5.4159072   5.40949612
 -1.91714216 -2.26650225 -3.7138887   5.98006425  4.72632669  5.20453338
  4.95046361  4.67806678  4.72286638  4.1850588   3.13116959  3.16862892
  2.73366898  1.72371214  3.53951691  3.86404861  3.51527105  3.90972208
  2.86340839  3.46975846  2.7687766   3.0284503   2.51227629  1.75161811
  0.95285671 -0.4655973   9.38224353  9.47766062  9.76635492  9.73635628
 -0.27367966  1.86275939  0.86102507  1.60947148  0.67562965  0.85894242
 -1.35537727 -0.85855513 -2.59942103  8.77070795  7.85437711  7.9078672
  7.37520837  7.47069689  6.97168053  7.64025685  7.56935214  7.80255101
 -2.85734751 -1.07975623 -5.10821411 -2.48103704 -5.50188297  7.66128659
  5.15799005  6.86371907  3.80742845  6.49294819  5.11835001  6.29209746
  4.57300885  5.73948154  3.72602271  4.93019252  3.34088625  4.22800894
  2.53747149  2.72044622]   [14.59399396 14.17538676 12.11253635 12.21898523 11.36216272 11.97824621
  9.49599821  9.19121228  8.68402685  8.89117939  7.32480894  7.91381899
  3.19143507  2.69871186  3.12348552  1.46258132 13.35418216 13.46758999
 12.36061903 13.11511372  8.45521196  9.08641432  8.5309354   8.56076844
  9.191071    8.53850611  7.24304758  7.83154007  7.04489     6.99701568
  0.5638625   0.19469849 -1.43943823 12.62988962 11.71885502 11.62566754
 12.05866517 11.57027291 10.51877182 11.33946178 11.31414447 11.48429395
  4.75474657  5.08202719  4.41086424  4.8373262   3.79586278  3.84440026
  2.9008565   1.95401438  0.81082048 14.46202919 13.22811087 13.82328719
 14.10304479 14.19299321  6.41208229  7.28931298  6.99147468  7.43798579
  6.29954869  7.04283397  6.3125048   6.52678372  6.01999398  5.56020142
  4.96703023  3.98429553  2.61200136  1.82232825 16.850672   16.44384111
  6.26819032  8.71002922  7.83320081  8.8212229   7.98323861  8.68625401
  6.96184901  8.32485726  7.58829445  7.95682585  7.26568654  7.27092631
  6.4217462   6.17293616  5.11895136  5.20220408  4.28081568  3.27553963
 -8.07712172 -4.79581853 -9.33932062 -3.55410904 -5.4922721  -4.98068847
 -3.50284453 -1.65739383 -5.26691215 -3.69863835 -0.64627254  0.28844521
 -0.69630747 -0.85757847 -3.41338786  3.70800446  1.63408755  3.1450509
  2.64204492  2.50336127]   [ 1.30114054e+00  8.15315156e+00  5.23930535e+00  5.01132982e+00
  4.45565040e+00  4.74180742e+00  1.14604320e+00 -6.73559045e-03
  6.78496283e+00  6.74663638e+00  5.07017488e+00  5.66409178e+00
  1.63733874e+00  1.25912340e+00  1.45420587e+00  1.24102954e-01
  6.94612171e+00  7.19239882e+00  5.99157573e+00  6.37614617e+00
  1.67897007e+00  2.24869726e+00  1.16807242e+00  3.35083369e-01
  2.19301137e-02  7.87804957e+00  6.39415667e+00  7.09650386e+00
  6.39578406e+00  6.62074804e+00  7.99959932e-01  1.15490059e+00
  2.47318786e-01  4.92876498e-02 -1.39700704e+00  7.65124721e+00
  7.48227097e+00  6.90380404e+00  5.91983503e+00  6.48870461e+00
  6.21423116e+00  6.37679250e+00 -4.34920957e-01 -6.00321151e-01
 -1.96827731e+00 -2.26992026e+00  6.81784002e+00  6.81568556e+00
  6.35956528e+00  6.29227876e+00  6.39250993e+00  5.80096255e+00
  4.94411213e+00  5.45219128e+00  5.24361831e+00  4.71206344e+00
 -3.74398461e+00 -3.96166348e+00  5.96680211e+00  6.03785540e+00
  4.70121252e+00  5.62892297e+00  5.05631239e+00  5.37750750e+00
  4.90252062e+00  4.74640875e+00  4.43255391e+00  3.77344892e+00
  2.66087389e+00  2.45855534e+00  1.53481055e+00  1.26065265e+01
  1.97353454e+00  4.51960506e+00  3.54980293e+00  4.50609317e+00
  3.49840571e+00  4.19961447e+00  2.20714105e+00  3.57672717e+00
  2.68321279e+00  2.72025529e+00  1.48633479e+00  9.59891660e-01
 -8.00455607e-01  1.09638382e+01  9.98456126e+00  1.06383717e+01
  1.05493328e+01  1.09708647e+01  7.43888050e-01  2.78464534e+00
 -3.07655161e-01  2.55644834e+00  8.40377970e-01  1.83414081e+00
 -3.99145423e-01  4.77315104e-01 -3.06103618e+00 -1.86959167e+00
  9.33159151e+00  9.66021669e+00  8.34340496e+00  9.23847458e+00
  7.80225548e+00  8.85027901e+00  8.09277237e+00  9.11936253e+00
  8.51739384e+00  9.25735251e+00]   [ 8.7746807   8.50527169  6.18449065  5.72511731  4.12625001  3.35894075
 13.68707776 12.97813629 12.60295852 13.01244433 11.83660687 12.51649823
  8.43366325  8.47280548  9.47910527  8.98201393  8.02320711  8.37003231
  7.04169735  7.16926569  1.91426947  1.65120342 -0.08205392 13.39191391
 13.52881059 12.96519714 12.03288501 12.7481386  12.21465451 12.64224632
  6.83771396  7.38086875  7.05853845  7.4940764   6.87205723  6.59423745
  6.58596952  5.5922075   4.03636266  3.85952638  2.35582845 16.70020835
  9.7802121  10.18159267  9.54239143 10.35201563  9.81068739 10.31050063
  9.95729237  9.87833452  9.94041346  9.42473993  8.60500549  9.00512293
  8.81699532  8.55190749  0.4586119   0.6053144  -0.71843353 -1.4951758
 11.93270089 12.49663713 11.8818076  12.27848105 11.95068557 11.98714091
 11.85704393 11.63471412 11.15727874 11.67565456 11.72611885 11.77094384
  1.46343637  3.97543463  2.77180999  3.31983273  1.73263685  1.88511749
 -0.94401385 -0.80031704 -2.53135343 -0.92449635 -2.84444137 -0.04797997
 -0.90177917 -1.6182753   1.2427764   2.15395051  1.32127769  0.79631879
 -5.11062163 -3.10984532 -5.53092354 -3.90661017 -6.30053893  0.73700249
 -2.15690124 -0.47499138 -2.97804509 -1.92889935 -3.76299996  3.74504845
  1.56555529  1.98075547  0.88244604  1.61251479 -0.14051652 -0.08338517
  6.61776443  6.98779591]   [ 6.11810619  5.98083022  4.46335971  4.21698354  2.58363314  1.95054541
  7.1441627   6.54703017  6.26560657  6.35671329  5.30001727  5.6827213
  1.38830303  0.44548006  0.33185371  8.33397437  7.29577365  7.74791931
  6.67299775  6.86612113  2.4948925   2.72224304  1.82625593  0.95363991
  0.38655253  9.01517432  7.83066075  8.25203463  7.60690456  7.74908084
  1.74899554  2.51306757  2.23489676  1.95912073  0.76823837 -0.33672514
  9.55970569  8.62066788  7.9146716   8.37406532  7.97313769  8.02162324
  1.76566115  2.15045202  0.8805645   1.19897017  0.07493811 -0.69998902
  9.18214126  8.6425589   8.51303327  8.13573162  7.69527632  8.02502877
  7.71098893  7.73024505  0.57354369  0.80584046 -0.41320126 -0.44468769
 -3.11611823  9.04216078  8.17653945  8.31461282  7.7758945   7.80135456
  7.50391063  7.25507496  6.78531649  7.04322748  6.69842074  6.46431534
 -3.55015897 -1.92091056 -3.82203769  8.55162325  6.84296438  7.74611465
  5.73950973  7.31454659  6.82563053  7.06496592  6.23868853  6.34944599
  5.52527565  5.4509146   4.68027495  4.54424724  3.5403263   2.71115104
  5.13755567  6.83998348  4.58780231  6.76014919  5.53833276  6.46002404
  4.72441272  6.06079692  3.65572558  5.39001709  4.55060578  4.65435803
  3.15056989  3.08321201  1.13596416  0.59857696 13.02216898 13.19224027
 12.81720677 13.32968484]   [12.7089459  12.71675932 11.20780617 11.39995159 10.70388087 10.77007591
  8.19830104  7.68702633  7.42698434  7.2518205   5.69900072  5.13203097
  0.39557732 13.67827776 13.8852568  13.48902448 13.11849501 13.52280391
 12.69314428 12.96853253  8.92336752  9.08105087  8.80828186  8.57779444
  8.68227512  8.04870269  7.27808688  7.13249279  5.80355315  5.16653256
 -1.99509752 13.07642876 12.79724273 12.90827863 12.52050106 12.45162473
 12.56260174 12.21922019 11.85851903 12.14648963 11.62733864 11.69063629
  5.63762171  5.99477105  4.7590756   5.31853939  4.61560375  4.07348835
  2.71502181  1.2843117  15.88855744 15.13404519 14.80479931 15.09227986
 14.82609206 15.00715414  8.53432524  8.99494314  8.30443942  9.08127099
  7.46401465  8.52655349  8.11183977  7.99574157  7.13613774  6.76190291
  5.88074426  5.07372122  3.98007457  2.82738588  1.28014044  2.71009949
 -6.94989482 -2.65881888 -3.50675844 -3.71843184 -1.72846045 -0.50861143
 -3.00286434 -2.57050771  1.26306969  1.30221658  0.98601033 -0.03314028
 -1.56826551  4.37796625  3.07227691  3.62277232  3.53862163  2.55933073
 -7.80545668  1.1158715  -1.55666162 -0.29086146 -1.05472296 -0.55586977
 -3.31247025 -2.88559027  2.25328933  3.31008262  2.44682573  2.47841962
  1.67640725  1.63557975 -0.27743426 -0.66182935  6.72225978  6.81070835
  6.37229095  6.43772756]
```

The expected results should be that each array will be in its own column. However, that is not the case. The actual results are that each array is just underneath each other.

Comment: It looks like you're using NumPy, which I'm not really familiar with.  It might be worth printing out the types of some of your variables.  Are the type of C and its elements what you expect?

Comment: Yes, the values of C look like what I should expect. Not sure, why It isn't printing out the arrays in different columns. I added more of my code. I think I might be writing the arrays wrong.

Comment: You can stack your arrays horizontally so they'll be in columns, then use numpy's `savetxt` with format to write the data at once.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: Could you should me how to write the code with stack? I keep getting only four columns instead of 8. When I do .vstack I basically get the same thing as above.